# Error en formulario para enviar mensajes a correo electronico

Tags: php, email

Hola amigos tengo el siguiente codigo (nota agrege el PHP al html5 para que vieran todo el codigo, No lo tengo asi ), bueno hace rato que lo tengo y me funcionaba correctamente y me llegaban los correos bien, pero desde que me salio un error de autentificacion de GMAIL,ya no me funciona, pero alto ya se soluciono lo de GMAIL,en donde tengo mal mi codigo?

no entiendo si antes me funciona correctamente,nota uso LAMPP en ubuntu/Escritorio version la version 16.4..

Mi codigo es este:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Ejemplo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

</head>
<style type="text/css">

body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
background-image:url("img/fondo.JPG");

}
  .alineacion{
  float: right;
}
</style>
<body>
</body>
</html>
<nav  class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Rosa susana</a>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
  <ul class="alineacion nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="inicio.html">Ver los caballos</a></li>

 </ul>
</div>
  </div>
</nav>  
<?php
$action=$_REQUEST['action'];
if ($action=="")    /* display the contact form */
{
?>
   <img class="avatar" src="Logo para web.svg" width="200px" height="200px">

<div class="col-md-6"></div> <!-- Columna vacía -->
<div class="col-md-12"><!-- Columna derecha con formulario -->
<form  style=" float:right;padding:10px;margin:10px;right:10px;margin-bottom:100px;" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <p style="color:white;">Tu nombre:</p>
<input placeholder="Nombre" required=""  name="name" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
<p style="color:white;">Tu email:</p>
<input placeholder="E-mail" required="" name="email" type="text" value="" size="30"/><br>
<p style="color:white;">Tu Direcion:</p>
<textarea placeholder="Direcion" required="" name="message" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea><br><br><br>
<input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Enviar mensaje"/>
<br>
<a href="chat-Messenger/J2TeaM-Facebook-Live-Chat-9231c6e/example.html">Si no se envian los mensajes comunicate por Atencion a Cliente.</a>
</form>
</div>
<?php
} 
else                /* send the submitted data */
{
$name=$_REQUEST['name'];
$email=$_REQUEST['email'];
$message=$_REQUEST['message'];
if (($name=="")||($email=="")||($message==""))
    {
 echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href=\"\">the form</a> again.";
    }
else{  
    $from="From: $name<$email>\r\nReturn-path: $email";
    $subject="CONTACTO CABALLO :)";
  mail("aquiestamicorreo@gmail.com", $subject, $message,$from);
 echo "Su Mensaje fue enviado con exito a nosotros!";
    echo "<a href='mail.php'></a>";
    }
}  
?>
<div style="color:white;font-family:arial; background:transparent;width:50%;padding-left:30px;" class="">
<p>Contacto:blablablablabla.</p>
<p>Correo: micorreo@gmail.com</p>
</div>
```

Donde dice "aquiestamicorreo@gmail.com" ahi puse mi correo donde me llegarian los mensajes.

Comment: ¿Revisaste la carpeta spam? Muchas veces los correos enviados desde el servidor van a parar a esa carpeta, por diversos motivos.

Comment: Es lo Primero que hice pero no esta :( mi ultimo correo spam es de hace 10 dias :(, lo curioso es que ya probe vario codigos similares que encontre por internet, como este : https://github.com/pinceladasdaweb/Simple-PHP-Contact-Form/blob/master/contact-form/config/config.php    y tanpoco funciona